# Weblogic 12.1.2.0 + Omnifaces 1.7 + Richfaces 4.3.5.Final deploy errors

Tags: jsf, richfaces, omnifaces

What steps will reproduce the problem?

1. Compile the attached project "GitHub Project URL", generate the .ear and try to deploy it to Weblogic 12c. It's a test project to reproduce the error.

What is the expected output? What do you see instead?

- I expect that the .ear can be deployed, it should show a dummy index page. Instead I see some deploy errors in the Weblogic log.

What OmniFaces version are you using? What JSF impl/version are you using?
What servletcontainer impl/version are you using? If any, what JSF
component library impl/version are you using?

- Omnifaces 1.7
- Richfaces 4.3.5.Final

*** You can see all the exact versions in the POM files

Please provide any additional information below.

The attach project *works fine* with Glassfish 3.1.2.2 and with WildFly 8, I need it to work on WebLogic 12c (12.1.2.0). If i use only Richfaces or only mnifaces, the project deploys ok to weblogic but if I try to use both then WL shows the errors on Log "Omnifaces + Richfaces" when I tried to fix the error adding the dependencies to the POM then WL shows the errors on Log "Omnifaces + Richfaces + Atmosphere Log".

I also made some tests using:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

But receives the same error that you can see in "Omnifaces + Richfaces + Atmosphere Log"

GitHub Project URL = https://github.com/mmonge/test_wl.git

**I Will add comments with the others links, this sites gives me an error "You need at least 10 reputation to post more than 2 links."**

** I'm sorry for my english, my native language is spanish.

Comment: Omnifaces + Richfaces Log = https://gist.github.com/mmonge/1701be12f34a3264afb9

Omnifaces + Richfaces + Atmosphere Log = https://gist.github.com/mmonge/e436c8f6a3ec9dbb4333

Comment: Apparently, WebLogic's CDI implementation is ignoring `VetoAnnotatedTypeExtension`. Technically, this is a bug in WebLogic itself and the server needs to be upgraded.